# Create a database view joining multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-view

I would like to get some help in creating a database view.
My DB schema looks as following:

```
products            (id, ignored_comments_ids (array))
activities          (id)
comments            (id)
activities_comments (activity_id comment_id)
products_comments   (product_id, comment_id)
offers              (product_id, activity_id)
```

Now I need to create a view of all products' comments with custom column named `source`:

- `source` = 'OFFER': comments coming from
  `products.offers.activities.comments` association
- `source` = 'DIRECT':
  comments coming from `products.comments` association

  Also, the view should exclude comments from `products.ignored_comments_ids`

How do I do that? The view has to have `product_id`, `source` and all columns from `comments` table.

I came up with the following view, how can I improve it?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW all_comments AS
  WITH the_comments AS (
    SELECT
      comments.*,
      'OFFER'     AS source,
      products.id AS product_id
    FROM comments
    JOIN activities_comments ON activities_comments.comment_id = comments.id
    JOIN activities          ON activities.id = activities_comments.activity_id
    JOIN offers              ON offers.activity_id = activities.id
    JOIN products            ON products.id = offers.product_id
  UNION
    SELECT
      comments.*,
      'DIRECT'    AS source,
      products.id AS product_id
    FROM comments
    JOIN products_comments ON products_comments.comment_id = comments.id
    JOIN products          ON products.id = products_comments.product_id
  )
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_comments.id)
    the_comments.id,
    the_comments.name,
    the_comments.source,
    the_comments.product_id
  FROM the_comments
  JOIN products ON products.id = the_comments.product_id
  WHERE NOT to_json(products.ignored_comment_ids)::jsonb @> the_comments.id::jsonb
  ORDER BY the_comments.id;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com is not a free coding service. What query have you attempted? Please add it to the question. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help especially under the heading **Asking**

Comment: @Used_By_Already I am quite new to DB. I think I would have to use `WITH` statement but what confuses me is the depth of associations and I am lost with all the joining I have to perform

Comment: Start with writing a select that returns the expected result. Then put "create view" before that select.

Comment: @jarlh right, I know the syntax of creating the view, as I wrote in my previous comment, the joining of tables is what's confusing

Comment: Take small steps. Start with joining to 2 tables. When it works fine, join with one more table etc.

Comment: if you never try you will never learn. Try  something. One join at a time is how every query is formed

Comment: @Used_By_Already assuming that the query I added to the question is correct in terms of joins, could you, please, suggest improvements or spot problems with it?

Comment: @jarlh assuming that the query I added to the question is correct in terms of joins, could you, please, suggest improvements or spot problems with it?

Comment: @Used_By_Already so it looks like you guys only judge hasty and that's all the help from your side :)

Comment: I suggest you reconsider how to interact with volunteers who try to help you. We needed to see any attempted query so that we could proceed. Then timing is always an issue (e.g.  I probably live on an opposite hemisphere and can't always be available) so the more prepared the question is generally the faster you will get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` may be used to combine 2 sets of data, AND, at the same time it will remove duplicate rows. `UNION ALL`  may be used to combine 2 sets of data (and then stops). So `UNION ALL` **avoids** the overhead of searching for, and removing, duplicated rows, so it is faster.

Within your initial common table expression (cte) `the_comments` you force each side of a union to use different constants, e.g.

```
select *
from (
    select 1 as id, 'OFFER' AS source
    union
    select 1 as id, 'DIRECT' AS source
    ) d
;
result:
  id   source  
 ---- -------- 
   1   DIRECT  
   1   OFFER
```

Even though id 1 is in both sides of that union, because of the different constants 2 rows are returned by that example query. So please use `UNION ALL` instead.

Despite the convenience of `select *` it should not be used in views (although there are arguments both ways, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select)). Perhaps this was done to simplify the question, but I hope it isn't used literally as seen. If the purpose of the view is to only return 4 columns then specify just those columns.

Although you need product_id in the output, this can be sourced from `offers.product_id` or `products_comments.product_id` so you don't actually need to join to the products table. There is no need for join to the products table after the cte either.

Because we are now using `UNION ALL` I cannot see any benefit is using `SELECT DISTINCT ON(...)`, I *suspect* this is just an overhead that can be removed. Obviously I cannot verify this and it may depend purely on your functional requirements. Also note that `SELECT DISTINCT ON(...)` will remove a `source` which you have so carefully introduced e.g.

```
select distinct on (id) id, source
from (
    select 1 as id, 'OFFER' AS source
    union
    select 1 as id, 'DIRECT'AS source
    ) d
;
result:
  id   source  
 ---- -------- 
   1   DIRECT
```

Do not include an `order by` clause in any view, only order a "final query". In other words; if you create a view you are then likely to use it in several other queries. Each of those queries will likely have their own where clause and need differing result orders. If you order the view you are just consuming cpu cycles and then dispensing with that effort later. So, please remove the order by clause.

I would dearly like to suggest a different approach to the final where clause, but as I don't deal with JSON very much I don't have sufficient experience to propose an alternative. However using functions on data in a where clause is almost always a cause of poor performance, most notably because it usually removes access to indexes on the columns involved in those functions. Finding a more efficient way to exclude comment exceptions is likely to make the largest improvement to your queries' performance.

So, my suggestions would lead to this:

```
WITH the_comments
AS (
    SELECT
        comments.id
      , comments.name
      , 'OFFER' AS source
      , offers.product_id AS product_id
    FROM comments
    JOIN activities_comments ON activities_comments.comment_id = comments.id
    JOIN activities ON activities.id = activities_comments.activity_id
    JOIN offers ON offers.activity_id = activities.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        comments.id
      , comments.name
      , 'DIRECT' AS source
      , products_comments.product_id AS product_id
    FROM comments
    JOIN products_comments ON products_comments.comment_id = comments.id
    )
SELECT
    the_comments.id
  , the_comments.name
  , the_comments.source
  , the_comments.product_id
FROM the_comments
/* perhaps raise a separate question on this bit */
WHERE NOT to_json(products.ignored_comment_ids)::jsonb @> the_comments.id::jsonb
```

Comment: Regarding JSON comparison in the final `WHERE` clause, at the very least this could be simplified to use an array contains (`@>`) rather than converting to JSON, ie: `WHERE NOT products.ignored_comment_ids @> ARRAY[the_comments.id]`.